# How to call functions in Javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got two functions :

```
    function startgame() {
"some code"
    }
    function return() {
"some other code"
    }
```

1) how to run functions here :

```
$( "#start" ).on('click', function() {
    /*I need my startgame function to run when the button is clicked*/
    });

    $( "#clear" ).on('click', function(){
    /*I need my return function to run in here*/
    });
```

2) Second question is what is the best way to call my functions in this code :

```
$( "#check" ).on('click', function() {
if ( $.inArray ( newword, words ) > -1 ) { 
/*here I need to run my return function*/;
} else {
g = g+6;//adds points
/*and here I need to run my startgame function*/;
}
});
```

Thanks !

Comment: Not really sure I get it, but `$( "#start" ).on('click', startgame);`

Comment: Also, you can call function by putting parenthesis after its name: `startgame()`. Not that you cannot use `return` as function name.

Comment: "return" is a reserved keyword, you can't call your function that.

Comment: yeah, I noticed my mistake with return, thanks

Answer (score 2):

[return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) is a reserved keyword. So i changed function name to `return_val`

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/9sPQ6/)

```
function startgame() {
    alert("startgame");
}

function return_val() {
    alert("return");
}
$("#start").on('click', startgame);

$("#clear").on('click',return_val);
```

Comment: @xdumaine yes keyboard buttons .

Comment: @xdumaine: Oh please don't argue about these kind of things. I'm not a fan of it either, but everyone can present the content of their post as they like, as long as the content is correct (and it's readable).

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#start" ).on('click', function() {
    startgame();
    });

    $( "#clear" ).on('click', function(){
    return_function()
    });
```

you can't call a retun as a function name , the simple answer for your question is just to call the function whenever you want using `Function_Name();`

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to create a function, you must know how to use or call them unless you had copied them elsewhere. In `JQUERY` you can call function with the function name followed by `()` and if that function accept params then put them inside `()` like

```
$( "#start" ).on('click', function() {
     startgame();
});

$( "#clear" ).on('click', function(){
    return_function()
});
```

You can also do

```
$( "#start" ).on('click', startgame());

$( "#clear" ).on('click', return_function());
```

It depends on how you need them.
Hope it helps!